# Section line dividers using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I wish to create a fancy line divider using tikz, to resemble the one shown below.
[image]

The divider is basically  a thin grey line with a larger rectangle on the upper side, such that the length of the rectangle is exactly equal to the length of the section title below it. I really have no idea how I can achieve this in LaTeX, and it seems like it may be rather complicated. Nevertheless, I would really appreciate some input.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0em}
{#1}
[{\color{gray!50}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
Text text text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far (MWE).

Comment: I've added a basic starting point. Perhaps you can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option `calcwidth` sets the register `\titlewidth` to the longest line in the title and is then the width for the thicker line. The thinner line follows with width `\linewidth`.

The rules are set before the title using `\vadjust pre` (keyword `pre` invented by pdfTeX and also implemented in XeTeX/LuaTeX).

TikZ is not necessary, the rules are drawn with `\hrule` of plain TeX.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}%
  [hang]% shape
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% format
  {}% label
  {0mm}% sep
  {%
    \vadjust pre{%
      \color{gray!50}%
      \hrule width \titlewidth height 4pt\relax
      \hrule width \linewidth height .4pt\relax
    }%
  }% before-code

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
Text text text

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! Surprisingly more simple than I thought it would be.

Comment: I've been using this divider for a year now and I've noticed that the vertical spacing between the title of the section and the bar is inconsistent. For example, try putting two sections one after the other. Is there a quick fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a conceivable way of adjusting the length of the gray bar to the length of the text. As requested in the title, it makes use of tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlength{\marmotlength}
\setlength{\marmotlength}{2.7cm}
\newcommand\myfancysection[1]{\addtolength\marmotlength{\widthof{\Large{\textbf{#1}}}}%
\typeout{feep \the\marmotlength}
\tikz[baseline=(CHAP.base),very thick]{
  \draw[use as bounding box,draw=white,fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
  \node[fill=white,minimum width=1.5cm,outer sep=0pt,rounded corners] (CHAP) at
  (1cm,\baselineskip+1ex) {\Large{\textbf{\textsf{\thesection}}}};
  \draw[black, line width=1pt](2cm,1.2cm) -- (\textwidth,1.2cm);
  \draw[gray!50!, line width=2mm](2cm,1.2cm) -- (\marmotlength,1.2cm);
}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont}{\myfancysection{#1}}{1em}{\Large{\textbf{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Blabla}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Blablablabla}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]